# Which instance of Map to use to store key/values with size restrictions in java

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures

I have to create a **Team** class which can contain information about a certain team size, for example - a football team could have 1 coach and 23 players, a basketball team - 1 coach and 15 players. I could use the coach as the key, but the value is a bit tricky, because the players have to split into two categories: starters and reserves, which can be a limited number, based on the sport: 11 starters and 6 reserves(football).
Im thinking it should be something like this: `private Map<Coach, Set<Athlete>> TeamList;` but that way i can't devide the players into starters and reserves, and also can't set a maximum team size. Which type of **Map** could i use to achieve this?

Comment: `Map<String, Team>` or just `Team[]` and `class Team {Coach coach; String name; whatever athletes; }`...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to distinguish information about a team by its data structure, in your case map. Instead, it would make sense to define a base class that contains the information that applies to all teams regardless of the sport. You can then extend this class and implement the details specific to each sport in the subclasses

```
class Team{
}

class FootballTeam extends Team{
}
class BasketballTeam extends Team{
}
```